# my div has a background even tho i don't want it and didn't set one

Tags: css

[Here you can see the background on the ankers that I don't want!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwuih.png)

**I'm pretty new to coding hopefully you can solve my problem very thankful for help in advance!**

> So the problem is basically that my ankers are showing a background that shouldn't be there, i added one for the whole page but didn't set one for the ankers. Also if I remove the background the ankers will get a white one (obviously). Also they have a really weird resolution and stretch over the screen what I don't want

```css
:root {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #272823;
}

/* COLOR CODES: #ffec4c, #848668, #272823*/

/* NAVBAR STYLING */

.navbar {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #272823;
    z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-box {
    position: relative;
    height: 101px;
}

.navbar-logo {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-logo img{
    width: 85px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 26px;
}

.navbar-menu {
    margin-right: 53px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    float: right;
}

.navbar-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-menu li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid #ffec4c;
}

.navbar-menu li a:hover {
    color: #ffec4c;
}

/* HOME STYLING */

.home-bg {
    padding-top: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    filter:blur(2px);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(172, 133, 28, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(img/Aliens\ Cows.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 603px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Daniel Salzmann</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Logo 1.png" type="image/icon type">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- nav seciton -->

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-box">
           <div class="navbar-logo"><img src="img/Logo 1.png" alt="Logo"></div>
                <ul class="navbar-menu">
                    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="creations.html">Creations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

<!-- home section -->

    <div class="home">
            <div class="home-text">
                <a class="text-1" href="creations.html">MY WORK</a>
                <a class="text-2" href="creations.html">SEE ALL MY WORK!</a>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="home-bg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the `* { ... }` rule you have `background: #272823;`. Try removing that.

Comment: How I already wrote it under the title if I remove it that there appears a white background for the ankers. Still thanks. I think it is something with the div the ankers are in but I can't find it.

Comment: add `background: transparent` in `* {...}` OR try to add background for `.home{background: red}`

Comment: * is a generic selector and apply the rules to all elements, so add the background only where is required.

Comment: I actually see my problem now, everything is fine except the text I added on the left site. (in the picture it sais "div.home-text). The problem is if I make the text bigger the whole background moves down and the background is more visible. But I want the text over the background picture.

Comment: thanks for the background it is fixed but I cant put the ankers on top of the picture

Answer (score 1):

From MDN: [Universal selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

> The CSS universal selector (*) matches elements of any type.
>
> ```css
> /* Selects all elements */
>
> * {   
>     color: green; 
> }
> ```

```css
* {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
<h4>more text</h4>
<div>this is a div</div>
<h5>another text</h5>
<article>something</article>
```

So instead of using `*` to add a background color you could just add the color to `body`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #272823;
}
```

And to make the text appear on top of the image add the following:

```css
.home-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is an example:

```css
:root {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #272823;
}

* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* COLOR CODES: #ffec4c, #848668, #272823*/


/* NAVBAR STYLING */

.navbar {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: #272823; */
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 101px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-logo img {
  width: 85px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 26px;
}

.navbar-menu {
  margin-right: 53px;
  margin-top: -60px;
  float: right;
}

.navbar-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-menu li a {
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease;
}

.navbar-menu li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #ffec4c;
}

.navbar-menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffec4c;
}


/* HOME STYLING */

.home-bg {
  padding-top: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  filter: blur(2px);
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, rgba(172, 133, 28, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSo3XYpwymh9Xsm2fOKWtEmnk971QTn8xyfU3fJwGFXpNh1Mt_9Ivge-pzlQJ3nO6VNfBA&usqp=CAU);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 603px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.home-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-box">
    <div class="navbar-logo">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/80JXf.jpg?s=48&g=1" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar-menu">
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="creations.html">Creations</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- home section -->

<div class="home">
  <div class="home-text">
    <a class="text-1" href="creations.html">MY WORK</a>
    <a class="text-2" href="creations.html">SEE ALL MY WORK!</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="home-bg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much man, really appreciate it!